# Socket connection to Heroku java server not working?

Tags: java, sockets, heroku

I have a simple Java server deployed on Heroku and I want to connect and send strings to and from it using Sockets from a client however I get no response when I send strings.

I have tried changing the port number from 80 to 443.

```
The server on Heroku:

public class Server {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Integer port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("PORT"));
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
      Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
      String inputLine;
      while((inputLine = in.readLine())!=null) {
        out.println(inputLine);
      }
  }
}
```

The client on my computer:

```
public class Client {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    try {
      Socket echoSocket = new Socket("minimal-java-web-app.herokuapp.com", 80);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

      String inputLine;
      out.println("Sent this message to server");
      while((inputLine = in.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println("got message: "+inputLine);
      }
      echoSocket.close();

  }
```

I expected an output of "got message: Sent this message to server" in the console when I run the client but I get nothing. No error or server response.

Comment: tested if the `accept()` is passed or any step that goes along at client side?

Comment: I added System.out.println(clientSocket.isConnected()); and it returned true in the Heroku logs --tail

Comment: maybe find which is the last line that print log